# How to launch Safari and reset Safari with applescript?

Tags: safari, applescript, reset, launch, automator

I am new to Applescript I fiddled around with Automator but I found it to be limited. I want to get into the coding side of the automation. I don't know if this is possible, what I would like to do with Applescript is:

1. Launch Safari, then
2. Click on a link, then
3. Reset safari
4. Click on a link
5. Reset safari

If I put in an example:

1. I launch Safari from Dock - this opens www.apple.com
   2 I click on the link "Support"
2. I go to Safari menu and from there I reset safari, it opens a Reset safari window and I click on Reset (then the safari goes back to homepage www.apple.com)
3. I click on "Support"
4. I go to Safari menu and from there I reset safari, it opens a Reset safari window and I click on Reset (then the safari goes back to homepage www.apple.com)

How can I do this with Applescript ?

Answer (score 2):

Next time please provide your code. Even an attempt will make other users more open to answering your question.  I don't understand why you would not go directly to the 2nd URL, unless of course you are trying to simulate traffic to a site. That being said, this should point you in the right direction:

```
repeat 2 times
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        set URL of document 1 to "http://www.apple.com/"
        delay 3
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('gn-support').childNodes[0].click()" in document 1
        delay 3
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            click menu item "Reset Safari…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
            delay 1
            click button "Reset" of window "Reset Safari"
            delay 1
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to responding.

Comment: You're welcome. If the response properly answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would lo into the Safari AppleScript dictionary. Many applications come with their own set of verbage that you can use directly by 'tell'ing that application to do something.

One way of opening a dictionary is to use the Open Dictionary item in the File menu of Script Editor.  When you use this item, you will get a listing of the available applications that have dictionaries.  Choose one and click the Open button or use the Browse button to navigate to an unlisted application.

As a head start, you can use *activate* to open an application and bring it to the front of your windows.

```
Tell application "Safari" to activate
```

Also you can make a new window:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
    make new document
end tell
```

I would first recommend looking through https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html and see if this answers any immediate questions.

Happy Applescripting!

Comment: Your example won't compile as written.

Comment: Feel free to make edits where necessary. I apologize for the deviation.